# Ruby/ROR Symbols Clarification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby/ROR and I'm kind of confused with something. A simple explanation would help.

1. Say I was linking to another page in Ruby on Rails. Would the keyword `link_to` be considered a method? Also, if so, where would I be able to learn more about these?
2. Symbols. What is the difference between a symbol with a colon on the :left or a symbol with a colon on the right:? Where would I be able to learn more about these?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: `link_to` is a helper method and you can read more about it [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). 

There's no difference between `:first_name => "Jelani"` and `first_name: "Jelani"` - the latter is newer syntax, but both work the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could use Google, e.g. https://www.google.de/search?q=rails+link_to. The `link_to` method is, well, a method which is defined by Rails and is not a Ruby keyword.
2. Symbols are different from Strings. In Ruby code, they are always written with a colon on the left. An "exception" of this rule is when it is used in a Hash using the new json-like Hash syntax from Ruby 1.9, where `{foo: "bar"}` is equivalent to `{:foo => "bar"}` Which variant you use is up to you, they are 100% equivalent.

Generally, it is probably a good idea to first read an introductional book about both Ruby and Rails or take an online-course, e.g. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ for learning Rails or http://rubykoans.com/ for learning Ruby.